# Retrieving data from realtime firebase and display in form of table on web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new firebase so i tried all possible ways to fetch the data from my real time database but unfortunately I am not getting how to do it?

```
<body>
<div id="bg">
  <img src="images/inventory.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<a href="#">
  <img id="logo" src="images/sitelogo.jpg" alt="Skype Logo">
</a>
<!--<form action="" method="post">
<table style="width:100%" id="ex-table">
  <tr id="tr">
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Name</th> 
    <th>Quantity</th>
</table>-->
<!--<p id="name">Name</p>
<p id="quantity">Quantity</p> -->
<table style="width:100%" id="ex-table">
  <tr id="tr">
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Name</th> 
    <th>Description</th>
</table> 
<script>
    var database = firebase.database();
    database.ref('Inventory').once('value', function(snapshot){
        if(snapshot.exists()){
            var content = '';
            snapshot.forEach(function(data){
                var val = data.val();
                content +='<tr>';
                content += '<td>' + val.category + '</td>';
                content += '<td>' + val.name + '</td>';
                content += '<td>' + val.quantity+ '</td>';
                content += '</tr>';
            });
            $('#ex-table').append(content);
        }
    });
</script>
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="addinventory.html">Add Inventory</a></li>
  <li><a href="viewinventory.html">View Inventory</a></li> 
</ul>
</nav> 
</body>
</html>
```

This code is not displaying y real time data as well as line `$('#ex-table').append(content);` is throwing an error that `$ is not defined`.I am attaching my database and current work done [image: My firebase structure]
 [image].This is my web page and there is one more error that My table header is not coming below nav bar.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `.once('value')` will get a snapshot, only once... It won't update in real time. Instead have a look at - It won't update in realtime. Try looking at `.on('value')` instead - it will trigger every-time the data changes. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events

Comment: `$` is not defined because you're trying to use a `jQuery` operator. Have you included the jquery library?

Comment: put/parse it with `.innerHTML` or instead of concatenating a string use `.createElement`

Comment: What's `firebase.database();`? I do not know about that. `$` is not defined means you have to add `jquery` file