# Log User Input(Online)

Tags: javascript, html, logging

I want to log users input by using a technology the most suitable & easy. How can I do it? I will not log another thing, only name & surname when user click submit.

```
console.log();
```

This does not work for me because it is local logging. I want if other user enter my website and write name & surname  after clicking submit button how can I log all input of users? Which free or paid technology is good for my aim?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The input element</h1>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>Click the "Submit" button and the form-data will be sent to a page on the 
server called "action_page.php".</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDİT:** I need a solution(3rd party solution because with backend it will be costly - not money, time costly.) without backend. Firebase may be good but it does not provide panel so reading data is problematic in Firebase. I need a solution better than Firebase Thanks..

Comment: You are not asking a specific programming question. You need to know HTML, CSS, JavaScript,  at least one Server Language, and one Database Language to program webpages. Most Languages are free, by the way.

Comment: Yes it is general question but how can I do this? I just want roadmap.

Comment: I use JavaScript's `XMLHttpRequest` to send data to PHP via `FormData`, before accessing a MySQL Database. `echo json_encode($objectOrAssocArray);` your results back to JavaScript from PHP to JavaScript. The process is well covered by a bunch of books and online tutorials.

Comment: I need a solution without backend because backend solution is complex for me. I just want to log two user input online nothing more.. Then backend is not a good solution for me I am looking for a solution like Firebase(maybe Google Tag Manager or Analytics - I do not know it is possible with GTM or Analytics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a 3rd party solution to log user input.(It's very easy & free!)

https://smtpjs.com

I send e-mail to my e-mail address when user clicks the button. As a result, I can log users easily.

```
<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js">
</script>
```

--

```
Email.send({
    Host : "smtp.yourisp.com",
    Username : "username",
    Password : "password",
    To : 'them@website.com',
    From : "you@isp.com",
    Subject : "This is the subject",
    Body : "And this is the body"
}).then(
  message => alert(message)
);
```

For SMTP you can use

https://elasticemail.com/account#/login

Configuration is easy & free!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I know you mentioned you didn't think this was for you, but the answers here wouldn't be complete without a plug for...

### Firebase Realtime Database

I know you said you didn't want firebase, but you should reconsider. I've found Firebase to be a very easy thing to setup, and you can get up and running at zero cost. In fact, their free tier is pretty generous and given the amount of responses you get, you might be able to stay in the free tier for a while.

- [NoSQL](https://www.dottedsquirrel.com/how-to-think-in-nosql-with-firebase/): You don't need to know SQL, set up databases or tables. You just send json data through javascript, using free javascript Firebase libraries.
- [Free tier](https://firebase.google.com/pricing): You can have up to 100 concurrent connections, 1 gig data storage for free forever - when you outgrow that, you just upgrade to their reasonable [blaze plan](https://firebase.google.com/pricing#blaze-calculator)
- [Google analytics integration](https://firebase.google.com/products/analytics)
- Panels: They do give you visibility into your database and you can look at it whenever you want. *Note: that does count as bandwidth.* Of course you have google analytics as well.
- [Easy to follow tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start) - this will get you up and running immediately... and a [LOAD of online documentation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs) This is google after all

#### Setup

This is all [detailed here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup), but the basic steps are...

- Sign into google firebase (w/ your google acct)
- Create a Firebase project (easy)
- Register your website with the project (easy)
- Add the `<script>`s (use their CDN) and the config object to your html page
- Start sending data

Aside from the configuration object, here's most of what you'd need to send your NoSQL database

```
let firstname = document.querySelector('#fname').value
let surname = document.querySelector('#lname').value
let userStore = firebase.database().ref("userStore/");
userStore.set ({
      firstname: firstname,
      surname: surname
});
```

#### Panel

All you need is a table that shows firstname, lastname and date submitted. That could be done in a simple HTML page.

- Here is a [youtube video showing how](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jOau1X5SKDE)
- Here is a [S.O. post complete with ready to copy/paste code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49546341/retrieving-data-from-realtime-firebase-and-display-in-form-of-table-on-web-page)

---

There are many ways of approaching this. You mention wanting access to a `panel` - but really with the minimal amount of data you're storing there isn't alot of panel needed. If you specify what kind of requirements you want from the panel, we could consider it in our answers.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. I need a panel for name & surname nothing more. When I implement it in my HTML, Firebase will provide like this structure(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuFBX.png) I know but it is not handy. I need a table that show all records like this. https://i.imgur.com/5mPSfDm.png My panel should be handy.. 
Thanks..

Comment: As easily as you create your form.html page, you could create a simple html page that fetches all your data - I updated my answer with a `Panel` section

Comment: what do you think about Google Analytics or Google Tag Manager? Is not it possible with GA or GTM?(Because maybe we do not need panel for GTM or GA)

Comment: @gurkanstack - GA is a powerful tool, but not a database. Same with GTA. From their website: _Other than data in standard HTTP request logs, all of which is deleted within 14 days of being received, Google Tag Manager does not collect, retain, or share any information about visitors to our customers' properties, including page URLs visited._

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**I think you are looking for a solution like [Netlify Forms](https://www.netlify.com/products/forms/).**

1. Simply add a `netlify` attribute to your form.
2. Host the web page with your form on Netlify.
3. There are various ways to check form submissions:

- [Via the Netlify GUI dashboard](https://docs.netlify.com/forms/submissions/#form-submissions-ui)

> You can find all submissions to your Netlify forms in your site’s Forms tab. Select a form name from the Active forms list to access the submissions for that form.

- [Programmatically via the API](https://docs.netlify.com/forms/submissions/#api-endpoints)

---

If you don't need any programmatic access, I suggest using one of the many 3rd party services like: https://paperform.co/

Answer (score 0):

You would need backend&database to do that. One of the easiest implementation would be with firebase authentication. Have a look at this page and firebase documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth

Comment: Can I do this with Google Analytics or Google Tag Manager? I am looking for the easiest way..

Comment: Not authentication, I just need to track what user typed.. Authentication is not required..

Comment: I do not know about them but firebase also from google and that's very basic to use if you check documentation

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Google Form`

https://www.google.com/forms/about/

Use could just go to your link and answer questions. You will then able to inspect all the inputs in your google account.

Comment: Is there any API for Google Form? I should not use Google Form I need to use HTML

Comment: @gurkanstack Yea, you could look into it see if it suits your needs. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to use node with express.js for your server-side language,
and then easily you can store users in a list in your server (add new user whenever the server receives a post request) , then you can log them or do whatever you want

Comment: It seems that it is a costly solution. I think I need 3rd party solution.

Comment: which  language you are using for your server

Comment: No backend, I need frontend solution.

Comment: unfortunately, there is no way to this without a backend, but you can go with a light solution  such as firebase check this  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start

Comment: Mohammad he is using PHP, based on the code

Comment: @mohammadisam what do you think about Google Tag Manager or Google Analytics? Is it possible to log user input online by using them?

Comment: sorry I haven't used them before so  I don't know much about them